# JavaScript String subclassing issue

Tags: javascript, string, subclass

I'm working on a simple browser mud-client, and i need to provide some basic functions to string processing. So, when some user casts a mass spell, it should be collapsed into a **one** string, i.e. `CAST: User1 -> [target1, target2]`. I wrote the code:

```
function CastGroup(caster, cast, targets, text) {
    this.cast = cast || '';
    this.targets = targets || [];
    this.caster = caster || '';
    this.text = text || '';
}

CastGroup.prototype = new String;

CastGroup.prototype.render = function(){
    var targets = this.targets ? '[' + this.targets.join(', ') + ']' : '';
    var text = '<b>CAST</b>: ' + this.caster + ' ' + this.cast + ' -> ' + targets + '\n';
    this.text = text;

    return new CastGroup(this.caster, this.cast, this.targets, this.text);
};

CastGroup.prototype.valueOf = function(){
    return this.text;
};

CastGroup.prototype.toString = function(){
    return this.render();
};


var c = new CastGroup('name', 'supercast', ['1', '2']);
console.log(typeof c); // object
var s = c.replace('name', 'nomnom');
console.log(typeof s); // string
```

Any string function, i.e. `String.replace()` replaces the original object. How can i avoid it?

## EDIT1

I have a post-process highlighting "engine", that calls user's callbacks. User should think, that bundle has only strings. `bundle` is an array with raw text, plain text, and colorized text. User defines callbacks in user-space, that should do all the highlighting work.

```
function process_highlights(bundle){
    if (!bundle || !bundle.length){
        return bundle;
    }

    var highlight_result = bundle;
    for (var i=0; i<HIGHLIGHTS.length; i++){
        highlight_result = HIGHLIGHTS[i](highlight_result);
    }
    return highlight_result;
}
```

So, text process chain looks like: **`original_bundle`** -> `subst_processor` -> `trigger_processor` -> `highlight_processor` -> **`output_window`**. All of these processors takes and return a bundle, that **should** contain strings. I cannot change the design now.

Comment: What do you mean it replaces the original object?

Comment: Because the replace calls the `toString()` method, which stores the string into `s`, it is not going to store the object in `c`.

Comment: epascarello, i see. But how to teach the replace method to use valueOf, and return `this`, not a new instance? I'm using subclassing because i don't want to break the original string functions.

Answer (score 0):

<del>If I understand your question correctly, you need to remove this: `CastGroup.prototype = new String;`</del>

<del>and do this: `CastGroup.prototype = String.prototype;`</del>

<del>This will give you the `String` methods without returning a new `String` object. To learn more about this (and about advanced Javascript in general), check out [these slides](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#76).</del>

### Update:

I think I understand your question a little better now. The `replace` string method returns a new string, which is why it's overwriting your object.

You don't need to inherit from the `String` object at all. `String` methods won't even work on an object (so delete `CastGroup.prototype = new String`). What you want to do is just modify the object's values directly.

If you need to modify the 'text' value of your `CastGroup`, then declare another method:

```
CastGroup.prototype.modifyText = function (findValue, replaceValue) {
    var text = this.text;
    this.text = text.replace(findValue, replaceValue);
    return this;
};
```

Comment: I have a text highlighting processor, that calls (may call) str.replace() after a CastGroup object was created. So, i need the `replace()` method to do nothing, but replace `this`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
CastGroup.prototype.replace = function() {
    this.text = this.text.replace.apply(this.text, arguments);
    return this;
};
```

Overwrite the prototype in your object, update the field that needs updating, then return the object.